# array of pointer pointing to arrays of strings

Tags: c, arrays, malloc

i created a code which transfers sentences from a file into arrays according to lines.
for example:

```
char ** Sentences[2]
Sentences[0]="hello ola hiya howdy"
Sentences[1]="chips fries"
```

i need to seperate each line into it's words(i already have a ready function which does that,and stores the output into a `char **` array.
i would like to store all arrays of words(in this case - 2,1 for each sentence) by creating an array of pointers to those arrays.
i will be more than glad to know how it's done.i also need to create a temporary array using malloc and stor the words in it,in order to dynamically create the arrays each time.

apposingly,can i use a char *** array and store the arrays created inside of it?

i will be more than glad for a solution.

Edit:
i created a memory allocating array,yet it keeps overriding itself:

```
char ** Temp=NULL;
         char **pointer[ir];

         for (Note = 0; Note < ir; ++Note) {
             Temp=malloc(Count(' ',Sentences[Note])*sizeof(char *));
                     int ifd=StoreArr(Sentences[Note],Temp," ");
                    pointer[Note]=&Temp;
                    printer(*(pointer[Note]),ifd);

         }
```

the output i get is this:

hello
ola
hiya
howdy
eitan
eitanon
eitanya

but if i call

```
printer(*(pointer[0]),3);
```

outside of the for,i get

```
 eitan
eitanon
eitanya
```

instead of the first words(which means the Temp does not allocate memory)?
i will be more than glad for assistance.

Comment: What exactly isn't clear about doing it?

Comment: i am struggling with 2 main thing:the first is creating the array:i have a function that returns the number of words in each line(for example - 4 at Sentences[0].i DO NOT know how to create a temporary array and malloc it's size to 4 cells for example,and in the next run - 2 cells(for the number of words in Sentences[1]).also,i do not know how to create an array of pointers to char ** arrays.

Comment: @user3005945 Enable compiler errors and try to compile the code you posted in the question.

Comment: this is only an example code.i need the basic explanation of how to define an array and malloc its size every time.for example:char**arg=malloc(number of words).after i store a pointer to this array(in the array pointer),the malloc should change(allocate a new array).so i need to know how to allocate this memory(of the number of cells in an array),and also,how to create an array of pointers to string arrays.

Comment: Temp=malloc(Count(' ',Sentences[Note])*sizeof(char *)) only overrides the content each time,and when i assign the pointers,all of them point to the last value(the value overrides).what can i do?

Answer (score 0):

For a sentence you only need a char pointer or a char pointer array to store multiple sentences.

Comment: okay.but i do not know how to allocate memory for a new array each time.when i allocate it like this:Temp=malloc(Count(' ',Sentences[Note])*sizeof(char *));,it simply overrides the existing each time.

Comment: I would store the words using a char ** pointer allocating memory like this: temp = malloc(numberofwords*sizeof(char*)); posting all your code would help more.

Comment: you did not include a code.my problem is that the char ** temp keeps overwriting itself for a reason.